# Once I nest buttons within another element, I can no longer toggle to "hide" them using my previous CSS?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I have the following component:

```
<div aura:id="appr">
    <ui:button aura:id="approveButton"  press="{!c.handleFirstPress}" label="Approve" />
</div>
<div aura:id="subm" class="hide">
    <ui:button aura:id="submitButton"  press="{!c.handleSecondPress}" class="hide" label="Submit" />
</div>
```

And javascript that utilizes the following CSS to toggle the buttons' visibility:

```
.THIS.hide {
display: none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;
}

.THIS.show  {
display: block !important;
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Relevant Javascript:

```
handleFirstPress : function(cmp) {
    var approveBtn = cmp.find("appr");
    var submitBtn = cmp.find("subm");

    $A.util.toggleClass(approveBtn, "hide");
    $A.util.toggleClass(submitBtn, "show");
}
```

But when I wrap the component snippet in a another div, the CSS is no longer applied and the buttons remain visible even when I try to toggle their visibility.

```
<div class="foo" > 
    <div aura:id="appr">
        <ui:button aura:id="approveButton"  press="{!c.handleFirstPress}" label="Approve" />
    </div>
    <div aura:id="subm" class="hide">
        <ui:button aura:id="submitButton"  press="{!c.handleSecondPress}" class="hide" label="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Why does this happen?**

Is it a lack in frontend knowledge, or lightning component related?

**How can I solve it?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a space when the element in the component is not a top level element:

```
.THIS .hide {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

.THIS .show  {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

For more info, see the [online help](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm).

Comment: The space being important because when there is no space the element that is matched must have both the `THIS` class as well as the `hide` (or `show`) classes directly on that element. With the space, you are instead looking for an element with a `THIS` class and then some descendant that has the other class. A good example of the difference: https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/